# How can I randomly match up the elements from multiple lists of the same length?

Tags: python, list, random

I created a cartesian product in a list and now i want to take out 4 different tuples randomly(my try at the end of the post).

```
shape = ['triangle' , 'square' , 'circle' , 'cross']
color = ['green' , 'red' , 'blue' , 'pink']

__cartesianPsc__ = list(itertools.product(shape , color))
```

My Cartesian product

```
[('triangle', 'green'), ('triangle', 'red'), ('triangle', 'blue'), ('triangle', 'pink'), ('square', 'green'), ('square', 'red'), ('square', 'blue'), ('square', 'pink'), ('circle', 'green'), ('circle', 'red'), ('circle', 'blue'), ('circle', 'pink'), ('cross', 'green'), ('cross', 'red'), ('cross', 'blue'), ('cross', 'pink')]
```

and now i want to make get 4 different tuples randomly with triangle,square,circle and cross and 4 different colors green,red,pink,blue, but every color and every shape/color is only one time existent
Example:

First pick

```
first = ('triangle', 'green')
second =  ('square', 'red')
third = ('circle', 'blue')
fourth = ('cross', 'pink')
```

Second

```
first = ('circle', 'blue')
second = ('cross', 'red') 
third = ('triangle', 'pink')
fourth = ('square', 'green')
```

etc

Does anybody know how to do this? I tried a While-Loop with random.range to pick one from triangle, square, circle, cross but i dont know how to do that to get the different colors

--------My old Code-----
i had the problem that it always had (triangle, green) as a tuple, but the other 3 tuples were different(every time).

```
shape = ['triangle' , 'square' , 'circle' , 'cross']
color = ['green' , 'red' , 'blue' , 'pink']

__cartesianPsc__ = list(itertools.product(shape , color))


while True:
    se1 = random.randrange(0, 4, 1)
    se2 = random.randrange(5, 8, 1)
    se3 = random.randrange(9, 12, 1)
    se4 = random.randrange(13, 16, 1)


# safe the randomly choosen tuple of the cartesian product
    first = __cartesianPsc__[se1] #triangle X color
    second = __cartesianPsc__[se2] # square X color
    third = __cartesianPsc__[se3] #circle X color
    fourth = __cartesianPsc__[se4] #cross X color

    
    # if statement to stop the While-LOOP only if there are 4 tuples with
    # 4 different shapes and colors !
    """Problem: (triangle, green) is always a tuple, no other color with triangle
    if  second[1] != first[1] and second[1] != third[1] and second[1] != fourth[1] \
    and third[1] != first[1] and third[1] != second[1] and third[1] != fourth[1] \
    and fourth[1] != first[1] and fourth[1] != second[1] and fourth[1] != third[1] \
    and first[1] != second[1] and first[1] != third[1] and first[1] != fourth[1]:
    """
 break
```

Comment: Don't create the cartesian product first. Just shuffle the shapes and the colors individually and `zip` them.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using double-underscores for `__cartesianPsc__`? Generally such underscores are used to represent magic objects. PEP8 says: "Never invent such names; only use them as documented"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending my comment: don't create the cartesian product at all. Just shuffle both shapes and colors, and `zip` them. I had to do it several times to get a different shape than `'triangle'` in the first position of the list, but that's just random.

```
>>> import random
>>> shape = ['triangle' , 'square' , 'circle' , 'cross']
>>> color = ['green' , 'red' , 'blue' , 'pink']
>>> random.shuffle(shape)
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>> list(zip(shape, color))
[('triangle', 'green'), ('cross', 'pink'), ('circle', 'red'), ('square', 'blue')]
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>> random.shuffle(shape)
>>> list(zip(shape, color))
[('triangle', 'red'), ('cross', 'blue'), ('square', 'green'), ('circle', 'pink')]
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>> random.shuffle(shape)
>>> list(zip(shape, color))
[('triangle', 'blue'), ('circle', 'green'), ('cross', 'red'), ('square', 'pink')]
>>> random.shuffle(shape)
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>> list(zip(shape, color))
[('triangle', 'pink'), ('cross', 'green'), ('square', 'red'), ('circle', 'blue')]
>>> random.shuffle(shape)
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>> list(zip(shape, color))
[('triangle', 'green'), ('square', 'pink'), ('cross', 'red'), ('circle', 'blue')]
>>> random.shuffle(shape)
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>> list(zip(shape, color))
[('cross', 'green'), ('square', 'red'), ('circle', 'blue'), ('triangle', 'pink')]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
import random
def get4Random():
    shape = ['triangle' , 'square' , 'circle' , 'cross']
    color = ['green' , 'red' , 'blue' , 'pink']
    random.shuffle(shape)
    random.shuffle(color)
    return zip(shape, color)
```

Shuffle each list randomly and then zip the shuffled values.